# PHP remove first zeros

Tags: php, formatting, string-formatting, zero, number-formatting

**Want to remove all `0` placed at the beginning of some variable.**

Some options:

1. if `$var = 0002`, we should strip first `000` (`$var = 2`)
2. if `var = 0203410` we should remove first `0` (`$var = 203410`)
3. if `var = 20000` - do nothing (`$var = 20000`)

**What is the solution?**

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Just cast it to integer

```
$var = (int)$var;
```

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Only if it is meant to be a statement instead of an expression.

Comment: it was not the entire line :) ehehhe

Comment: is there similar function in javascript?

Comment: of course, casting is a feature present in almost every language.

In JS you can use parseInt()

Comment: (int)$var is an statement, but assigning it to $var looks like a expression to me. Anyway, this is a oneliner, you don't need to add something else after it.

Comment: @Workinghard, `parseInt(var, 10)` or `1 * var` (my favorite :))

Comment: @Lekensteyn: `(int)$var` is an expression and an assignment is an expression too.

Comment: Just remember if you do it this way (int)$var, and the number is above max integer, 2147483647 - then your number will change and not only remove the zero

Comment: When I tried this solution in php version 5.3.3 and not working as expected.  I tried with $var = 0131;$var = (int)$var);echo $var; it results 89.

Comment: @viswa Google for "89 to octal"

Comment: Of course it is an I interpreter behaviour to treat a number starting g with 0 as an octal representation of an integer .. I think the "printed number" in the question was in fact it's striking g representation .. maybe it cab be investigated deeper

Comment: @drAlberT So what is the point my value got changed and if I try to get a value from an array using this value as key then, I will get an in-appropriate result or empty result.

Comment: I really think the "pseudo code" in the question was referring to *strings* .. 
an octal number IS already an int .. the representation is not influent on the value.

Your test should be on `$var = '0131';`, a string.

Comment: Watch your step. That only works for integers! If the value is a decimal number, then the decimal is removed. Therefore, I think ltrim is the better idea to remove leading zeros (as the title of the question is)

Comment: true, but the question was for integers ;)

Answer (score 35):

Maybe `ltrim`?

```
$var = ltrim($var, '0');
```

Comment: Yes, this way we don't affect possible decimal places.

Answer (score 16):

```
$var = ltrim($var, '0');
```

This only works on strings, numbers starting with a 0 will be interpreted as octal numbers, multiple zero's are ignored.

Answer (score 5):

```
$var = strval(intval($var));
```

or if you don't care about it remaining a string, just convert to int and leave it at that.

Answer (score 5):

Just use + inside variables:

```
echo +$var;
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you post a link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: Really I have no reference! but works like a charm! change strings to numbers and remove all unnecessary zero and change string to number.

Comment: A + unary operator acts on numbers, so you are doing an implicit cast ... bad code as it hides the logic with no other advantages IMHO ...

Comment: Nice try, it work in Javascript but with PHP, you just cast the var :-D

Comment: loll... I like your reply @poostchi. it works like a charm indeed. I just used it in my project. but the fact that there's no relevant documentation got me thinking :(

Comment: Documentation : it is called "identity" → https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 2):

Carefull on the casting type;

```
var_dump([
    '0014010011071152',
    '0014010011071152'*1,
    (int)'0014010011071152',
    intval('0014010011071152')
]);
```

Prints:

```
array(4) {
    [0]=> string(16) "0014010011071152"
    [1]=> float(14010011071152)
    [2]=> int(2147483647)
    [3]=> int(2147483647)
}
```

Comment: for [2]=> int(2147483647)
    [3]=> int(2147483647) its integer overflow , so results will not be expected if value is more than max integer limit i.e. 2,147,483,647 (or hexadecimal 7FFFFFFF16)

Answer (score 2):

Multiply it by 1

```
$var = "0000000000010";
print $var * 1;  

//prints 10
```