# Remove characters from a string till another character comes

Tags: php, string

How do I remove characters till there comes another character in a string?

For example:

String is this: `0030051`

Now I want to remove ALL `0`'s before another character (like: `1`) comes.
So the string will become this: `30051`.

Is there a PHP function for this or is this easier with Javascript/jQuery ? (I'd prefer PHP)

Comment: is this what you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563740/php-remove-first-zeros ?

Comment: You want to remove preceeding zeros.?Is that what you want.?

Comment: you want to remove 0's only or any characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cast it to integer

```
$var = (int)$var;
```

[Source - Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563740/php-remove-first-zeros)