# format numbers to eliminate zeros on left

Tags: php, format, substr

I need help in keeping just the number in the RIGHT (before the zeros) In this example:

`$var = 'LMO0000000381W'` => keep just 381

I started with `substr($var, 3, -1);` which give me `0000000381` but it's the zeros that might be inside other numbers that bothers me. those are cases I need to be valid

```
0000000381 => 381
0000003081 => 3081
0000030810 => 30810
0000053081 => 53081
```

Comment: The strings start with letters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP remove first zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563740/php-remove-first-zeros)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've extracted the number, which is the difficult part, almost anything will do:

```
<?php

$data = '0000000381';
var_dump( (int)$data );
var_dump( (float)$data );
var_dump( number_format($data) );
var_dump( sprintf('%d', $data) );
```

... prints:

```
int(381)
float(381)
string(3) "381"
string(3) "381"
```

---

Edit: if you want some other ideas, here's a not fully tested regular expression:

```
$var = 'LMO0000000381W';
if( preg_match('/^[A-Z]*0*([0-9]+)[A-Z]*$/i', $var, $matches) ){
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

But your system is just fine.

Comment: Casting it is. Totally forgot the obvious solution, thx for reminding me (y)

Answer (score 4):

Given `$var = 'LMO0000000381W'` with the letters, this should do it:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^1-9]*([0-9]*)/', '$1', $var);
```

Or:

```
preg_match('/[1-9]\d+/', $var, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```

Comment: Edited and added a match also.

Answer (score 2):

We have these two methods to do this

1.Using ltrim function of PHP

```
$str = ltrim($str, '0');
```

2.Using typecast

```
 `(string)((int)"00000234892839")`
```